# What terminology is used to describe spacecraft in stationkeeping?

Tags: nasa, terminology, esa, station-keeping, roscosmos

Forgive any inaccurate wording of this question.

If a Soyuz craft which had been docked at the Zvezda module backed away from the ISS and remained at stationkeeping, would NASA, Roscosmos, or the ESA refer to the position of the spacecraft as being astern of the station?  If not, what word is used to describe a craft at stationkeeping at that position.

Comment: So the spacecraft is in the same orbit as the ISS but phased such that it is "behind" it (located in the retrograde direction wrt ISS) and looking at the Zvezda's engine? Is that the configuration that you are describing and asking about?

Comment: I only know of retrograde as meaning "orbital or rotational motion of an object in the direction opposite the rotation of its primary."

Comment: That's *retrograde motion*, but at least here, for the purposes of confirming your scenario, can we assume that *retrograde direction* is a direction, and that it is opposite to the *prograde direction* (the direction that they are moving)?

Comment: -vbar.  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/position-of-shuttle-viz-iss

Comment: @BowlOfRed for a moment I thought that was a cousin of fubar

Comment: @BowlOfRed sounds like a answer to me!

Comment: I heard of the term "hovering" when a spacecraft maintains its relative position w.r.t. a specific point

Comment: @Julio Where did you hear "hovering" being used?

Comment: Mostly in academia, both applied to asteroid and geocentric operations:https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/1.3890   https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/1.G000004